# Is it recommended to send tags sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I have a dynamic website and i currently have submitted to Google Webmaster Tools, Sitemaps Section, about 1,600,000 user generated items.

All this items also have tags added by users, so my question is, if i create a sitemap for those tags (there are about 4,000,000) will help my index more page or it will be considered by Google as spam.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As long as those tag pages has enought different content, even if there are some blocks that are being reused, it is ok.

What could be worse is if there are several tags with the same blocks and only changing a H1 and the title.

But it all depends on if the tag pages are usefull on it's own to a random visitor, if not then avoid listing and block that on robot.txt to improve spider timing.